# SSH private and public key creation and setup

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I'm attempting to gain access to a web server using an SSH key.

I followed several steps to create my keys, had them uploaded and am still unable to connect.

In Git Bash (on Windows 8) I checked for existing keys:

> ls -al ~/.ssh

When there were none, I created one with:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@mydomain.com"

I saved it in the default setting which seems to have been C:/home/.ssh, and I gave it a passphrase.

I was basically following the beginning of the [github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

This generated me an id_rsa file and an id_rsa.pub file. The first was uploaded by the server administrator, and I'm attempting to log on now.

PuTTY can't use the id_rsa key as it is ("Unable to use key file  (OpenSSH-2 private key)"), so I converted it using puttygen to pvtky.ppk.

I then just see "login as:", without the key error, but can't log in with anything.

I'm not asking asking for help in conjuring up a login, just trying to understand if my process was correct, as I expect it really wasn't, and if what I'm seeing is expected at this point.

EDIT: PuTTY raw errors:

> Event Log: Reading private key file "C:\home.ssh\pvtky.ppk"
>
> Event Log: Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
>
> Event Log: Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
>
> Event Log: Configured key file not in Pageant
>
> Event Log: Offered public key
>
> Event Log: Server refused our key
>
> Event Log: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Comment: if you are in windows, you can skip putty and download cygwin and install the openssh package within it, and use ssh within cygwin

Comment: *The first was uploaded by the server administrator, and I'm attempting to log on now.*: You should "upload" the second, the `id_rsa.pub`. And you actually do not upload it, but rather put a fingerprint of it to `authorized_keys` file. But I hope your administrator knows.

Comment: What does PuTTY show in its Event log? (include it into your question).

Comment: Using SSH packets logging I was able to pick out a few of the event log errors. I'd added them to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much direct help to your question of using ssh-keygen properly,I prefer using [PuttyGen](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe) for my .PPK creation needs.

Comment: I used PuttyGen for creating my PPK. But I'm not sure what the difference is between the .ppk file and the ones I created with gitbash are. Or what creating a ppk from my id_rsa.pub using puttygen file actually did.

Answer (score 0):

there will be

> pageant.exe

in putty installed folder

open it, then you can see its icon in systems tray
 right click on it and

> add key

option

select your .ppk and add it